# Segfault after using pointers in vector in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, segmentation-fault

i am running into a segfault in my c++ program and can't figure out my mistake.
I have a class Map which is a 2D-vector of objects of the class MapCells. The task is to go from cell to cell. From each cell, there are two possible ways to other cells. Maybe some 'pseudo' code can explain it better:

```cpp
//map.h

class MapCell {
private:
    MapCell *p_way1_, *p_way2_;
    int some_information_;

public:
    MapCell* getWayPointer1();
    MapCell* getWayPointer2();
    int getInformation();

    void setWayPointer1(MapCell* new_p_way1);
    void setWayPointer1(MapCell* new_p_way2);
};

class Map {
private:
    std::vector< std::vector<MapCell> > map_;
public:
    void initializeMap();
    MapCell* getStartPointer();
};

int main()
{
    Map map;
    map.initializeMap();

    MapCell *p_current_cell, *p_next_cell;
    p_current_cell = map.getStartPointer();

    while(p_current_cell->getInformation() != 0)
    {
        if(p_current_cell->getInformation() == 1)
        {
            p_next_cell = p_current_cell->getWayPointer1();
        }
        else
        {
            p_next_cell = p_current_cell->getWayPointer2();
        }

        p_current_cell = p_next_cell;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is only a little part of the real code. But i think i made a fundamental mistake so i hope this is enough code to fix it.
The problem is, that my code runs for minutes without problems and suddenly i get a segfault. gdb states, that the segfault happens when getInformation() is called. <strike>I also found out, that at some point all p_way2_ vectors lead to nonsense.</strike> Can you help me?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Without seeing the implementations of your `getStartPointer` and `getInformation`, etc, it's impossible to say what may be going wrong.

Comment: I agree with the first comment. It's likely your cycle termination condition is problematic. Are you sure the way pointers in each cell are set? Maybe initializing them to NULL and checking for NULL in the cycle would be safer approach.

Comment: getInformation() is a regular getter function. getStarterPointer() is just like `return &map_.at(0).at(0);`.

Comment: If above mentioned functions don't modify the container, We would like to know how void *initializeMap()* is implemented.

Comment: After the map is initialized, there are no NULL pointers. Everything is fine. Actually, in my program the cycle i stated above is called several times. I checked the pointers at different times. It seems like the pointers get more and more messy with the time, but never when i use the map. Is it possible that the map gets reallocated even when my program is doing something completely different?  How can i 'follow' the addresses of the MapCells?

Answer (score 0):

Problem in lines

```
MapCell* p_current_cell, p_next_cell;

MapCell* p_way1_, p_way2;
```

Second parameter is not pointer and MapCell is implicit convert from pointers (or you will get multiple compile-times errors).
Try change to

```
MapCell* p_current_cell, *p_next_cell;

MapCell* p_way1_, *p_way2;
```

Comment: Sorry, these are only mistakes in the question. The actual code is correct considering this.